# Separate Array into two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, split

I wonder how I can separate an array that consists of "123.152323,152.123232" into "123.152323" and "152.123232".

I pick up the string from a rest, the string looks like this.

responseHandler({"items":[{"name":"xxx","location":["xx.xxxxx","xx.xxxxx"]...

```
    function responseHandler(json) {
        var markers = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < json.items.length; i++) {
            markers[i] = (json.items[i].location);
        }
}
```

Can I split the location before putting it into an array? I know split() exists but if the string has more information than just location, such as name, city, etc.

Comment: You mean, it's JSON? Parse it using `JSON.Parse` and fall back on `eval`...

Comment: why can't you treat this string as json?

Comment: @minitech: Doesn't look like JSON to me; rather, it's an actual "JSO"! He's mislabelled his variable.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel ?  It seems like you have a valid json object, Why not simply use [JQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Comment: When did he say anything about using jQuery?

Comment: I only recommended a good external library to use instead of reinventing JSON parsing from scratch.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar: Noone needs to "reinvent JSON parsing from scratch". Modern browsers have JSON.parse and old browsers can use eval('(' + jsonStr + ')'). Remember that JSON was purposely designed to be easy to parse on Javascript - JQuery's parseJSON is mostly there for convenience and consistence for those already using JQuery

Comment: Do *not* use `eval` unless you are very sure of the source of the string.  You are handing over the keys to the kingdom when you do that.  In fact, do not use `eval` even if you are very sure of the source, it's just not worth it.  JQuery will do a nice parse, natively if possible, as quickly as possible otherwise.

Comment: @Malvolio `jQuery.parseJSON` also uses `new Function` as a fallback (more or less equivalent of `eval`).

Comment: Doesn't look like JSON to me. It's an actual object [literal].

Comment: @Malvolio: Though, if anything critical can be done through JavaScript the security's pretty bad.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar Take [a look](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L537) at how jQuery parses JSON through it's mighty abstractions and say again how difficult "reinventing JSON parsing from scratch" is.

Comment: @Zirak You see it simple enough to warrant a "reinventing" I see few error checks there that most people who reinvent it will forget about.

Comment: @minitech I assume you do still do all your banking the old way..by actually going to the bank

Comment: @parapurarajkumar I see one error check that will get noticed in proper debugging session. And I also see thousands of other lines, which would also be included and never used because reinventing that wheel is so difficult...

Comment: @parapurarajkumar: I'm 14, I don't do banking ;) If you'd like a better response, next time try leaving a less cryptic comment. You know what they say about assumptions...

Answer (score 0):

Modern browser contain native JSON methods (like `JSON.parse`, `JSON.stringify`). Use those, or use an external library like [this one from google](http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/). It makes your life easier (no need for splitting or regex searches and the like):

```
function responseHandler(json) {
   // use native (JSON.parse), json-sans-eval would be: jsonParse(json)
   var  myJson  = JSON.parse(json)  
       ,markers = []
       ,i       = 0
       ,len     = myJson.length;
   for (; i < len; i = i+1) {
       markers.push(myJson[i].location);
   }
   return markers;
}
```

**Edit after comment**: you are passing a js-object, so JSON-parsing is not necessary.

```
function responseHandler(json) {
   var  markers = []
       ,i       = 0
       ,len     = json.length;
   for (; i < len; i = i+1) {
       markers.push(json.items[i].location);
   }
   return markers;
}
//for example
var json = {"items":[
                     {"name":"xxx","location":["xx.xxxxx","xx.xxxxx"]},
                     {"name":"yyy","location":["yy.yyyyy","yy.yyyyy"]}
                   ]
           };
var locations = responseHandler(json);
//=> now locations[0][0] is 'xx.xxxxx', locations[1][0] 'yy.yyyyy'
```

(May be you should try finding some reading material on the web about [javascript basics](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/index4.htm))

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your reply, I've tried your solution but can't get it to work. The string I receive looks like this.

responseHandler({"items":[{"name":"xxx","location":["xx.xxxxx","xx.xxxxx"],...

Comment: In that case no parsing should be necessary (you are passing a genuine js-object), so you can push `json.items[i].location` directly to the array.

Comment: Alright, that works, thanks! :) but how do I split the array into two arrays connected to each other? Now when I do an alert(markers[0]) I get xx.xxxxx,xx.xxxxx . Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are missing something. Markers[0] is the original array from the location property of the first element of the items array. It has 2 elements, so `markers[0][0]` and `markers[0][1]` are your values. Try studying http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays

Comment: Thanks. Now it works! Great :) yeah I'm really novice on this area...!